# How to configure log-driver in kubernetes pods file?

Tags: logging, docker, kubernetes

below is docker run command:

```
docker run --log-driver=syslog
```

How to set **log-driver** in kubsernetes pods.
Can you show examples to me?
Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

There is an open feature request for this, but it's not yet supported:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15478

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an equivalent of setting log-driver on a per-container basis in Kubernetes. Can you elaborate on what your goal is so I can help you better?

Comment: Thanks @Alex Robinson
I have setup a cluster by k8s,now I need collect cluster logging.Have try many way,finally choose elk+logstash+kibana to collection(look like it`s a better way).
Now I can`t find logging about every container.

Comment: How did you set up your cluster and stack? I'd recommend taking a look at the guide for getting cluster level logging to elasticsearch and kibana set up in your cluster: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/logging-elasticsearch.html

Comment: I have try the "cluster level logging" solution,but it`s has some risk for me(It`s will using many resource,will be affect my app running.).
So I try other ways.